# google map v2 issue with uft8 string for title in android

Tags: android, google-maps, utf-8, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android project,in this project i have  google map view and i use google map v2 . The problem is, i have some MarkerOption and i'm setting a utf8 string for them but the titles are shown as an empty string

here is my code for adding markers:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("سلام");
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

how can i solve this?

thanks for any helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must set an English word then set your string :

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("TEST:"+"سلام");
```

Comment: A much more delicate solution posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26947047/3249477).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unicode left-to-right mark ("\u200e") to your text, like:

```
.title("\u200e" + "سلام");
```